# Downloading start after Facebook share

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to start the downloading of a document when user share a link on their Facebook, Google+ or Tweet.
I am opening a window on click of share button, which get closed after sharing. But I am not able to start downloading(means start a event).

Please help

```
<a id = "facebookShare" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&u=www.abc.com" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"></a>
```

How to append a function here, which can call download start ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `javascript:` in an onClick, just call the code directly.

PS. The way you ask this makes you sound like a spammer.

Comment: Ha Ha..what made you feel I sound like spammer ? If I use window.open directly then also same I can't trigger the download event after share window close..

Comment: The part where you won't let the document start until the user spams their friends

Comment: I am just a developer sir...client is offering a handbook, so they want user to do something before they get a copy of it..

Comment: @RajeevKumar I'm pretty sure there is no way to detect if they actually clicked the share button, but you have to check with fracebook to see if the facebook javascript API notifies you in some way. I would simply open the share window, and start the download at the same time, and if they don't actually click share, then they don't. Forcing them to click share is pretty nasty. Well, actually I would just give them the doc, and if the like it let them click share on their own. Anyway, the code you posted does nothing because you have `javascript:` in it, so that's my answer.